# What is absent in go that C++ has?

Tags: go

Go is meant to be a simple language and there is about 25keywords. Because it is simple i was wondering what does it not have compared to other language like C++ or C# (which IMO is more complex than C++)

I understand its simple bc it has less keywords and other things but i dont know the langauge so what did it have to tradeoff or leave out because of that decision?

Comment: A language could be quite complex and have very few keywords (stricto sensu, PL/1 had no keywords, since thy could be employed in the role of identifiers).

Comment: A lot of C++ complexity is related to the fact that it wants to be compatible, or at least interoperable, with C; Go has no such requirement.

Comment: ok but still, go leaves out templates (afaik) and i am sure a lot of other things. I just have no idea what. cc @BasileStarynkevitch

Answer (score 3):

As others commented, number of keywords is not a metric for simplicity, but you're right that Go is simple. I don't know C#, but here are some essential C++ features not available in Go:

- **Generics (templates)**. There's been a long discussion about how to have support for generics in Go. They may come someday, but not yet.
- **Inheritance**. Go's typing model just doesn't work like that. That means there's no overloading, no protected fields, no polymorphism, etc.
- **Exception handling**. Panic and recover covers that, but it's not exception handling.
- **Constructors and destructors**. Types have initial values and that's all.
- **C macros**.

I may be missing something.

**EDIT:** I missed **pointer arithmetic‌​**.

Comment: [pointer arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_%28computer_programming%29#Go)?

Comment: I was afraid of missing inheritance and polymorphism. I'm using them extensively for this project :(. I guess thats why they say use the right tool for the right job

Comment: I would recommend you to take a deeper look at Go's type system. Go's idea of interfaces and embedding are simpler but also more powerful than inheritance and polymorphism (they also cover some of the cases where other languages usually require generics). It just takes some time to forget everything you have heard about OOP before :)

Comment: @oers: Go has pointer arithmetic. You just have to cast a Go pointer to an "unsafe.Pointer" before, if you really want to use pointer arithmetic (you usually dont want to do that).

Comment: @acidzombie24 Inheritance and polymorphism are not synonyms. Go does not have inheritance, but does have polymorphism.

Comment: @acidzombie24 I guess we use inheritance and polymorphism and such things in projects because we know them and are used to solving problems with them, not because the actual problem demands them. Most of the times the same problem can be approached from a different view and be solved in a profound way.

Comment: Go provides a destructor mechanism via "runtime.SetFinalizer".  See http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#SetFinalizer